# How can I make Kubernetes use a private repository by default with Nexus and Containerd?

Tags: kubernetes, nexus, containerd

K8S need to use private repo by default

I'm currently trying to use Nexus Repo by default for Kubernetes. But I have 2 problems. The first one is that if I don't specify the repository, it will directly search on docker.io, despite the fact that I've specified. Also my K8S is using containerd.

/etc/containerd/config.toml

```
[plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.mirrors."docker.io"]
endpoint = ["http://192...:8082"]
```

Furthermore, even when I specify the image with the repository, there seems to be an issue. It's not a connection problem because I was able to ping the repository.

describe of the pod

```
Events:
│   Type     Reason     Age    From               Message      
│   ----     ------     ----   ----               -------
│   Normal   Pulling    2m17s  kubelet            Pulling image "repo.mm.mm:8082/nginx:latest"
│   Warning  Failed     2m17s  kubelet            Failed to pull image "repo.mm.mm:8082/nginx:latest": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image "repo.mm.mm:8082/nginx:latest": failed to resolve reference "repo.mm.mm:8082/nginx:latest": failed to do request: Head "https://repo.mm.mm:8082/v2/nginx/manifests/latest": dial tcp 192...:8082: connect: connection refused
│   Warning  Failed     2m17s  kubelet            Error: ErrImagePull
│   Normal   BackOff    2m17s  kubelet            Back-off pulling image "repo.mm.mm:8082/nginx:latest" 
│   Warning  Failed     2m17s  kubelet            Error: ImagePullBackOff  
│   Normal   Scheduled  2s     default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/ng-test to worker1
```

If anyone has encountered a similar issue or has any suggestions for resolving these problems, your assistance would be highly appreciated. Thank you in advance!